# Date display differences in node templates

Tags: theming, 8

In a node template, if I use the following:

```
{{ content.field_event_start_date }}
```

The correct localized date and time will be displayed.  For example:

Tuesday, February 14, 2017 @ 9:00am EDT

However, if I only want to display the time part and use the following:

```
{{ node.field_event_start_date.value|date("g:ia") }}
```

The incorrect time is displayed:

1:00pm

There appears to be a +4h offset when using the TWIG date() filter.

Drupal's Timezone is set to "America/New York".

How can I display only the time part so that it correctly displays the following?

9:00am

Also, can you please explain what conversion Drupal is performing on the time under the covers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The proper thing to do here is to configure your field output to use the proper formatter.  On the **Manage Display** for your content type, eg admin/structure/types/manage/page/display, change the formatter for your `field_event_start_date` field to **Custom**, then click on the gear and change the format to 'g:ia'.  You should then be able to use `{{ content.field_event_start_date }}` in your template.

The standard Twig `date()` filter doesn't use the `date.formatter` service, so timezones and localization settings will not be honored.

[`TwigExtension`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/class/TwigExtension/8.2.x) defines a custom filter for Drupal that will call out to [`DateFormatter::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.2.x) called `format_date()`.  This should work

```
{{ node.field_event_start_date.value|format_date("custom", "g:ia") }}
```

This apparently only works for Timestamp fields and not datetime or daterange fields.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain about the syntax there, as I don't think I have ever used this directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation.  I tried your suggestion, but it seems that it will only work if the particular field is of type "timestamp".  The field that I am using is of type "date".  Here's what Drupal output when I tried:

`Exception: The timestamp must be numeric. in Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromTimestamp() (line 172 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php).`

Anything else that I can try?  Thanks again!

Comment: @kvjava1 Sorry about that; Twig is pushing the limits of what I do in Drupal 8 and I am not sure how to extract the timestamp in a template.  I assume using the custom formatter, and using the 'g:ia' format isn't an option?

Comment: It's ok.  Can you clarify (and/or give an example of) what you mean by "using the custom formatter, and using the 'g:ia' format"?

Comment: I even tried converting the "datetime" to a "timestamp" and then doing `{{ node.field_event_start_date.value|date('U')|format_date("custom", "g:ia", "America/New_York") }}`, but that didn't work either. :(  If I use "PST" for the timezone instead of "America/New_York", then it works, but I'm in "EST" so I don't like that hack. :(  Trying to figure out what's going on with Drupal internals...?

Comment: Using date('U') in addition to formate_date('custom', ...) did the trick for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your node in THEME.theme (or in a module if you prefer, note that my field is 'field_date' you will need to adapt to your field machine name).

I copy the field using another display formatter. I'm using datetime_custom formatter, but you can use whatever you want.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  // Extract the hour from the field_date so we can easily display concert_time
  if(!empty($node->field_date)){
    $variables['concert_time'] = $node->field_date->view([
      'type' => 'datetime_custom',
      'settings' => ['date_format' => 'H:i'],
    ]);
  }
}
```

Then in your twig

```
{{ concert_time }}
```